# How to handle data inconsistency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

My applications is on Spring MVC 4.2 with postgres database. In my application, we are consuming an API which is written using spring boot having its own database (mysql).

```
@Transaction(rollbackfor = Exception.class)
updateOrder(Order order) {

    // This insert is part of my application
    update(order); //**STEP - 1**

   //This is not part of our application &
   // happening in api written in spring boot.
   Integer transactionId = updateOrderWorkflow(order);// **STEP - 2**

   //Below updateOrderWithTransactionId is part of my application
   //Updates the order with the transaction Id
   updateOrderWithTransactionId(order, transactionId); //**STEP - 3**
}
```

If STEP-3 fails, then I have to rollback the changes made in the consuming api. For rolling back I have written compensation/rollback method, which rolls back to the old workflow status.

**Now the problem scenario:**

If one process (PROCESS_1) is working on the above updateOrder() method and reaches to STEP-3, but before this process FAILS in STEP-3, another process (PROCESS_2) tries to access the updateOrder() method and updates STEP-2. Now PROCESS_1 fails in STEP-3 and it calls compensation/rollback method, but PROCESS_2 completes STEP-3 successfully.

This creates data inconsistency. How to handle this situation?

Comment: it sounds like the external API at step 2 needs to change - do you have any control over it?

Comment: Yes, that too we have created.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is that `updateOrderWorkflow` in step 2 exposes the changes made by the transaction of PROCESS_1 before it has been committed.

What I would do is:

- Change `updateOrderWorkflow` in step 2 so that it doesn't show uncommitted changes. Any changes it makes have to be made in a temporary space of some kind, associated with the transaction ID.
- Add an API endpoint to this same API, to commit or roll back the changes of a transaction. If committed, the changes in the temporary space are made visible globally. If rolled back, the changes are discarded.
- Use the new commit API endpoint in your `updateOrder` method, and the rollback API in your rollback handler.